# How an open Succah must be oriented?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

THe Halachah allows a Succah to have only 2 walls and something (or 3 walls), so a big opening is, therefore possible.

Assuming I erect a Succah in my backyard and any direction is possible, what side should this opening be facing?

Comment: Why would there be any halachic difference which side the opening is facing?

Comment: @IsraelReader THis is exactly what the question is about - are there any Halachic ramifications?

Comment: @AlBerko This question would be improved with a justification for the question. In order to not be a low-quality question, this question needs a reason why one might think one way or another might be preferable. Otherwise I may as well ask any random question to find out if there's a halakhic preference (e.g. should my bedroom be on the first floor or the second floor? Given no other options, should I choose to wear shoes that are too big or too small?)

Comment: @AlBerko from the way the question is worded it sounds like you assume there is a preference not if you are asking if there is one. “What side should this opening be facing” vs is there a halachik preference for which side this opening be facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halachically speaking, there is no mention of any requirement which side the opening should be be facing.

However, practically speaking, you would want the opening to be facing the side which gives you the most privacy.

Alternatively, you would want the walls to shelter you from wind, in the best possible manner. Therefore the opening should face the direction where the least wind would come in.